# Is it possible to create a desktop apps and an android apps (mobile) with MySQL?

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-studio, netbeans

I want to make a desktop apps and an android apps (mobile)
For desktop apps, i want to use java and netbeans, for android applications I also use java for language and android studio

So my question is, is it possible to create a desktop application and an adroid apps (mobile) with one database: MySQL? Does the data exchange require use web service?

Comment: Yes, you need a web service

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, but you might want to do a lot of research before jumping into it. When setting up a server to connect to from standalone devices there are a lot of things to consider. [Here](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JDBC_Basic.html) is a source to start researching:

Answer (score 0):

The important keyword would be [model-view-controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). ([other source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mvc-design-pattern/)).

It basically means that in general System you have 3 different Parts/Components (Or how you want to call it). The short explanation:

**Model**: The first is the Model. The Model is anything that is data related. In your case that would be your MySql Database System.

**View**:The you have the View which is anything that the user sees and interacts with.

**Controller**: The Task of the Controller is to make sure that the UI is provided with the model and that the model is updated by the UI.

This is a pattern, meaning it does not care what language you use. In your case I would say, that your MySql Database is the Model and the UIs are the Android and Desktop app.

In simpler constellations the e.g. android app has an internal "Database" if any, Controls the UI with java and the UI would be the xml Stuff. 
In this case you would have a 1:1 relation between Model and UI so you need one Controller.

In your case however you want to connect a desktop UI and an android UI to your database which is a 1:n relation. This connection mostly possible through the internet so you need the MySql Database accessible from the internet, meaning running on a server.

Though probably not the best but simplest (for me) setup would be [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html). 
Then it highly depends on your use-case and will to scale, but a proper highly scalable solution I would go for (but is by no means the only or always the best solution) is a the [Backend-for-Frontend-Pattern](https://samnewman.io/patterns/architectural/bff/).

This means you have a dedicated server for your particular Frontend (UI).

In general I would do a lot more research about architecture, because if you mess up the architectural design, you lose a lot of time fixing it afterwards. Make sure you have identified all important features and use-cases and the general vision of your project before you start implementing.

Maybe you can use systems from different people for less money than paying a developer to implement the same thing again.

So make sure that each component has good reason why its being implemented other than the language that is known to you and your team.

Hope that helps.